# Remove "game.php?name=" from URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have url www.domain.com/game.php?name=football and it dynamically get 'football' datas, and I want do the same with www.domain.com/football

How can I make it with .htaccess?

Thank you.

Comment: Search `url rewriting htaccess` on google, and you will find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Turn on rewrite engine in your htaccess and add

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ game.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]